# Disable airplay in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur, macos-monterey

I have been running some containers and applications on some ports in mac for local development and they were working fine (Atleast in catalina and Big sur). To be more specific I was using port 7000 for running an application for local development. It seems like since some patched update of Monterey, Control centre is running Airplay on ports 5000 and 7000.

I don't use Airplay and I am fine to disable it. However after digging through internet, I haven't been able to achieve it.

One option that was recommended somewhere was to strip the permissions of AirPlayUIAgent using root access.

`sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent`

However I am not allowed to do it and I am met with an "operation not permitted"

Is there a way to disable airplay at all in Monterey? It used to be just a toggle in display preferences. Good old days.

Comment: use "csrutil disable" in Recovery Mode to disable SIP > restart > and then you should be able to call "sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent" after that > reenable SIP with "csrutil enable" again in Recovery Mode to prevent a Security Hole ... Hope that does the trick (I'm still on Big Sur) ... Cheetz DaVe

Comment: Seems easier to just change your app's port though.